# How to add extra python-only functions in a pybind11 project built with scikit

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to build upon this amazing example: https://github.com/pybind/scikit_build_example

I basically want to figure out how to add more functions or classes that are purely python. I thought I would need to add them to `src/scikit_build_example` as separate `*.py` files. For instance, add a file called `cube.py`:

```
from _core import square

def cube(num):
    return num * square(num)
```

where I've defined an additional `square` function on the C++ side, as a part of the `_core` module.

But, when I do `pip install` and try to use it, I get

```
AttributeError: module 'scikit_build_example' has no attribute 'cube'
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: So, I fetched the example, added implementation of `square` to the C++ code, added `square` to the existing `__init__.py` (would have been easier if you either mentioned that, or used a function that already exists there). I created `cube.py` as you described, and fixed the import statement to read `from ._core import square` to avoid a `ModuleNotFoundError`. | If it build a wheel (`pip wheel .`), all the files are there as expected. If I install it, I can do things like `from scikit_build_example import cube`, or `from scikit_build_example.cube import cube` just fine, and call the function.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for that. Sorry I forgot to add the info about `square`.  So I'd forgotten the `.` in front of `._core`, and can now do the import as you note. What would I need to add to `__init__.py` so that I can just do `from scikit_build_example import cube`?

Comment: Do `from .cube import cube` and then add `"cube"` to the list assigned to [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/3962537).

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you!